# a word to describe the situation where A was supposed to do something for B, but B does it for A

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any appropriate word to refer the following sort of situation?

*when someone wakes us up whom we were supposed to wake up*

Comment: Can I just clarify, do you mean strictly a single-word answer? I see that you've tagged your question "single-word-request, I fear my answer is wrong.

Comment: An example sentence always helps with this sort of question - @Sarah can you add one please?

Comment: for example,  we say 'ad nauseasm' when someone repeats the same always. Likewise, If x told y to wake him up at 5am, but then the reverse had happened.  Is there any specific word (may be in hilarious tone)  to specify  in this situation?

Comment: (1) What does “ad nauseam” have to do with anything else on this page? (2) You misspelled “ad nauseam”. (3) “An example sentence” means a sentence in which the word that you want might be used (with a blank space left for it). You should [edit] your question and add such an example sentence.  (4) Look up “reciprocity” and see if it’s what you want, or close to it.

Answer (score 2):

Role reversal

> noun
>  a circumstance wherein two people adopt the opposite role of
>   their normal one or switch normal roles
>  [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/role-reversal)

Parents are supposed to take care of their kids, but as people age these roles often reverse to the point where the parents need caretaking by their children.